# Django IndexView does not refresh current date

Tags: python, django

I am using Django `IndexView` to display main page in my application with some data.
The data contains field named `date_time`.

I want to display data for `date_time` range starting from current time when I visit page to some point in future

My code looks like below:

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    """View class for home page"""
    template_name = 'core/index.html'
    model = Match
    context_object_name = 'match_list'
    now = datetime.now()
    queryset = Match.objects.filter(season__is_active=True, date_time__range=(now, "2050-12-31"))
```

Unfortunately Django the value for variable `now` is not updating when I visit the page, instead it is the date when I start the Django application.

Is this behaviour caused by using `IndexView`? Should use some other view instead?

Comment: Can you share **Match** model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the filter in `get_queryset()` in order to re-calculate the current timestamp.

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    """View class for home page"""
    template_name = 'core/index.html'
    model = Match
    context_object_name = 'match_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(season__is_active=True, date_time__range=(now, "2050-12-31"))
```

Also, you should probably use `now` from `django.utils.timezone` as that one is timezone aware.

---

Here's a quotation from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views) explaining why `now` (which is a class attribute in your question' code) is not updating when you visit the page.

> While your class is instantiated for each request dispatched to it,
> class attributes set through the as_view() entry point are configured
> only once at the time your URLs are imported.